# How to remove json element?

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

I'am using dataTables plugin for my table, and it has an json data from the database like :

```
{"sEcho":0,
"iTotalRecords":1,
"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,
"aaData":[["contentFieldA","contentFieldB","contentFieldC"],
          ["contentFieldA","contentFieldB","contentFieldC"]],
"sColumns":"fieldA,fieldB,fieldC"}
```

for some reason I need to remove the "aaData" and "sColumns" value on the first index (so "contentFieldA" and "fieldA" should be removed). and the json data will be :

```
{"sEcho":0,
 "iTotalRecords":1,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords":1,
 "aaData":[["contentFieldB","contentFieldC"],
           ["contentFieldB","contentFieldC"]],
 "sColumns":"fieldB,fieldC"}
```

Can anyone help me.. Thanks

Comment: What are "some reasons"? Assuming you use the serverSided example code for server sided query, dataTables will generate a mySQL query for you that fetches these rows from your db and returns them via json. If you don't want to have these columns in your dataTable you simply should not fetch them. Just leave them out in the server_processing.php $columns configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have :

```
var test = {"sEcho":0,
"iTotalRecords":1,
"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,
"aaData":[["contentFieldA","contentFieldB","contentFieldC"],
          ["contentFieldA","contentFieldB","contentFieldC"]],
"sColumns":"fieldA,fieldB,fieldC"};
```

`aaData` is an array of arrays, so remove first index of each subarray like this :

```
for (var i=0;i<test['aaData'].length;i++) {
    test['aaData'][i].splice(0,1);
}
```

deleting first index from `sColumns` is a little bit harder, since it is a string :

```
test['sColumns']=test['sColumns'].split(',').splice(1,2).join();
```

Notice that `splice(1,2)` is hardcoded, if you have 4 columns it should be `splice(1,3)`, 5 columns `splice(1,4)` and so on.

Running those two cleanups will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in JSON, you can use regular expression and remove what you want:

PHP: https://www.php.net/preg_replace
JS: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp